# How to distribute exponentiation over multiplication?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I would expect the following:

```
FullSimplify[(a*b)^i, a > 0 && b > 0 && i > 0]
```

to give me `a^i * b^i` as output. Much like `(a*b)^2` is immediately reduced to `a^2 * b^2`. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Generally speaking `LeafCount[(a b)^i] < LeafCount[a^i b^i]`, so it would require some special simplification rule for `Simplify` to give you what you want. As I understand it, the `(a b)^2` case is not being simplified, but simply processed that way by the parser before evaluation.

Comment: `Distribute[(a*b)^i,Times, Power]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the default [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction) considers `a^i b^i` to be more complex than `(a b)^i`, hence your desired form will not be returned.

Besides using [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand), you could also use a [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction) that penalizes complex expressions in the base of [`Power`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Power) objects:

```
cf[expr_] := LeafCount[expr] + Total @ Cases[expr, Power[a_, _] :> 10 LeafCount[a], All]
FullSimplify[
    (a b)^i,
    a>0 && b>0 && i>0,
    ComplexityFunction -> cf
]
```

> a^i b^i

Answer (score 4):

```
(a*b)^i // PowerExpand
```

> a^i b^i

As @MarcoB points out, there are many assumptions here, [detailed in the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html): in this case, it is assumed that `i` is an integer and `a` and  `b` are positive real numbers.

Comment: ... with the usual caveat that `PowerExpand` makes some assumptions (real values of variables), which happen to be upheld in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

The simple `ComplexityFunction`

```
cf[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 10 Count[e, _Times]
```

also works:

```
FullSimplify[(a b)^i, a > 0 && b > 0 && i > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf]
(* a^i b^i *)
```

If `(a b)^i` lies lower in the expression, then its level must be specified.  For instance,

```
cf2[e_] := LeafCount[e] + 10 Count[e, _Times, {2}]
FullSimplify[1 + (a b)^i, a > 0 && b > 0 && i > 0, ComplexityFunction -> cf2]
(* 1 + a^i b^i *)
```